# Fixed header behaving differently in Firefox

Tags: css

I have two slide menus on my website, one on the left and one on the right. I also have a fixed header, that is pushed left or right alongside the rest of the content, depending on which menu is opened.

This is causing some issues in Firefox – when the right-hand menu is opened by clicking the orange button, the header stays in place and doesn't move with the rest of the content. This doesn't happen with the left-hand menu. I can see why this might occur, given that it's `position:fixed`, however I can't see why it's only Firefox that acts this way. Is there a way around this?

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
text
</div>

<footer class="footer">
Footer
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:pink;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1); 
}

body {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 

    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    position:fixed;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
}

.content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    width:85%;
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:20px;
}

.footer {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;        
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#button-one {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#button-two {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.push-menu-one {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:-295px;
    width:295px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:wheat;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.push-menu-two {
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   right:-295px;
   width:295px;
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:darkred;
   -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
   transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0;v
    transition: opacity 1s, width 0s ease 1s, height 0s ease 1s;
}

.overlay.open-right,
.overlay.open-left {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.4;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

/* TOGGLE CLASSES */

```
html.open-left {
    left:295px;
}

.push-menu-one.open-left {
    left:0;
}

html.open-right {
    left:-295px;
}

.push-menu-two.open-right {
    right:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#button-one').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one').toggleClass('open-left');

    });

    $('#button-two').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-two').toggleClass('open-right');

    });

    $('.overlay').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-left');

        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-right');

    });

});
```

Comment: Clearly appears to be a Firefox quirk. Everything seems to work fine in Chrome, IE11 and Edge. Have you tried applying the `html` styles to `body` instead? Maybe FF doesn't appreciate transitioning and positioning the root element.

Comment: Also note that any subsequent event (a click, a window re-size, etc.), suddenly re-positions the layout in FF.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. I can't remember what exactly happened when I tried it and I'm not in front of the computer at the moment so can't check, but I remember it having strange results. I've just realised that it's doing the same thing in safari on my iPhone, minus the sudden repositions that you noticed. I'll have a go at adding another div later on as a wrapper instead of using html

Comment: Ok, I've tried using `body` and `.wrapper` and it's doing the same thing. Not sure what to make of this. Do you think it could be to do with the fact that the slide menus are child divs within the header?

Comment: Hi Jack, it's going to take some time to debug. But I'm getting ready for work this morning, so I can't help much right now. What I would suggest is you strip down the code to a single line. Then start rebuilding again, one line at a time. Test in FF at each step. Eventually, hopefully, you'll find the culprit. (For the sake of simplicity, get rid of all the prefixes, you don't need them for this test.)

Comment: Good idea, I'll have a go at this now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a bit of messing around I pinpointed it to the `left` and `position:relative` of the `html` element.

So now I've used `transform:translate3d` to move the elements around, as  I've read that this doesn't rely on css positioning to work (absolute, relative etc).

This has unfortunately come with it's own set of problems, one of which is that the header no longer seems to be fixed when I scroll up and down when the menus are open, but I guess that's an issue for a separate question.

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/8/

**Updated CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100 % ;
    background - color: pink;

}

body {
    min - height: 100 % ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: -webkit - box;
    display: -webkit - flex;
    display: -ms - flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -
    webkit - box - orient: vertical; -
    webkit - box - direction: normal; -
    webkit - flex - direction: column; -
    ms - flex - direction: column;
    flex - direction: column;

    -
    webkit - transition: all .6 s cubic - bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: all .6 s cubic - bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 70 px;
    width: 100 % ;
    background - color: white;
}

.content {
    -webkit - box - flex: 1; -
    webkit - flex: 1; -
    ms - flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    width: 85 % ;
    margin - top: 80 px;
    margin - left: auto;
    margin - right: auto;
    padding - top: 20 px;
}

.footer {
    display: -webkit - box;
    display: -webkit - flex;
    display: -ms - flexbox;
    display: flex; -
    webkit - box - orient: vertical; -
    webkit - box - direction: normal; -
    webkit - flex - direction: column; -
    ms - flex - direction: column;
    flex - direction: column; -
    webkit - box - align: center; -
    webkit - align - items: center; -
    ms - flex - align: center;
    align - items: center;

    height: auto;
    width: 100 % ;
    padding: 10 px 0 10 px 0;
    background - color: #efefef;
}

#button-one {
    display: inline - block;
    width: 30 px;
    height: 30 px;
    margin: 20 px;
    background - color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#button-two {
    display: inline - block;
    float: right;
    width: 30 px;
    height: 30 px;
    margin: 20 px;
    background - color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.push-menu-one {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0 px;
    left: -295 px;
    width: 295 px;
    height: 100 % ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background - color: wheat; -
    webkit - transition: all .6 s cubic - bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: all .6 s cubic - bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}

.push-menu-two {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0 px;
    right: -295 px;
    width: 295 px;
    height: 100 % ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background - color: darkred; -
    webkit - transition: all .6 s cubic - bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: all .6 s cubic - bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z - index: 9;
    top: 0 px;
    left: 0 px;
    width: 0 px;
    height: 0 px;
    background - color: #000000;
    opacity:0;

    transition: opacity 1s, width 0s ease 1s, height 0s ease 1s;
}

.overlay.open-right,
.overlay.open-left {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.4;

    transition: opacity 1s;
}

body.open-left {
    transform:translate3d(295px,0px,0px)
}


body.open-right {
    transform:translate3d(-295px,0px,0px)
}

.header.open-left {position:fixed;}
```